# Longest common subsequence between lists of sequences

Tags: algorithm, sequence, dynamic-programming

The length of the longest common subsequence (LCS) of sequences a and b can be computed in `O(len(a)len(b))` time by

```
if a[i] != b[j]
    c[i, j] = max(c[i - 1][j], c[i][j - 1])
else
    c[i][j] = max(c[i - 1][j], c[i][j - 1], 1 + c[i - 1][j - 1])
```

where `c[i][j]` is the length of the LCS of `a[0:i]` and `b[0:j]`. How fast can you compute the LCS of all pairs of sequences between `x` and `y`, where `x` and `y` are lists of sequences?

I tried directly computing each pair, which takes

[image: Quadratic time in the length of either list]

time, which is the product of the total sequence lengths of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Terrible formatting aside, your question needs to include an explanation of your own approach to solving this problem. Please click [edit] to explain what you have tried.

Comment: Plaintext or something like LaTeX?

Comment: Stack Overflow supports its own formatting tags - a subset of HTML tags plus some special formatting rules.

Answer (score 0):

First things first,

your recurrence relation is ***wrong***

LCS (assuming bottom up as you have)

```
if a[i] != b[j]
    c[i, j] = max(c[i - 1][j], c[i][j - 1]) # fine
else
    c[i][j] = 1 + c[i - 1][j - 1] # NO NEED FOR MAX HERE!! You can't have longer subsequence with a shorter string!
```

Now, to answer your questions, if you were not using dynamic programming (or if you did and you encountered the worst case of no overlapping subproblems ever) then you cannot do better than LCS x Quadriatic time.

Otherwise

What you can do top optimize is add another layer of dynamic programming.

assuming a top down approach, do not erase the map that contains the LCS between 2 substrings, allowing you to resuse the subproblems in later computations

Python like pseudo code:

```
seq_lcs_map = map()

def computeLCS(str1, str2):
    if str1.empty() or str2.empty():
        return 0
    try:
        return seq_lcs_map[(str1,str2)]
    catch:
        try:
            seq_lcs_map[(str2,str1)]
        catch:
            if str1[0] == str2[0]:
                seq_lcs_map[(str1,str2)] = 1 + computeLCS(str1[1:], str2[1:])
            else:
                seq_lcs_map[(str1,str2)] = max(computeLCS(str1[1:],str2), computeLCS(str1,str2[1:]))
            seq_lcs_map[(str2, str1)] = seq_lcs_map[(str1, str2)]
            return seq_lcs_map[(str1, str2)]


def batch_LCS(l1, l2):
    for i in l1:
        for j in l2:
            try:
                seq_lcs_map[(i,j)]
            catch:
                try:
                    seq_lcs_map[(j,i)]
                catch:
                    seq_lcs_map[(i,j)] = seq_lcs_map[(j,i)] = computeLCS(i,j)
```

Note: A little bit of redundancy when it comes map keys but better to catch some weird edge case than try to be super optimal